# Flutter dynamic module loading

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, dynamic-loading

I'm trying to implement a plugin architecture in flutter to add or remove plugins from code during runtime, so I wanted to know if there a way to load modules dynamically like importlib in python? or an equivalent of it? If there's no dynamic module loading, how can I simulate a similar behavior?